# Where is SystemCredential stored on Windows?

Tags: windows, cryptography

Where is `SystemCredential` stored on Windows by default? (if stored in registry what is the registry path and if stored inside a file what is the file path). Is it possible to specify a certain file for storage?

```
SystemCredential["Test"]=SystemCredentialData[<|"username"->"testname","password"->"1234567890"|>,"password"];
```

Now `SystemCredentialKeys[All]` shows that it is stored and can be retrieved by `SystemCredential["Test"]` even after the session closes, so is persistent.

Comment: I am voting to close this question since it has nothing to do with Mathematica, really :) As explained in the documentation: _Credential stores are also called keychains or keyrings, depending on the operating system used. If possible, $SystemCredentialStore is set up to use the **operating system's keychain**._ Therefore, run `control /name Microsoft.CredentialManager` (or go to `Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager`), and you will see your credentials there. For specifics of implementation, refer to [SuperUser SE](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Or ServerFault: [Where does Credential Manager store credentials on the file system?](https://serverfault.com/questions/770996/where-does-credential-manager-store-credentials-on-the-file-system).

Comment: @Domen what about if we set `$SystemCredentialStore=SystemCredentialStoreObject[<|"Backend"-> "EncryptedFile","Keyring"->"MyKeyring"|>]` where is the `EncryptedFile` location in that case?

Comment: Everything is explained in the documentation for [`SystemCredentialStoreObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemCredentialStoreObject.html) ...